MSE read-only mode banner links are useless
The MSE banner,

This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon. Visit our status page or search our recent meta posts on the topic for more info.

has two links, neither of which The are MSE-specific.  The status page has nothing about MSE.  The meta page is SE's meta, not math.meta.SE.  Perhaps this banner should have links that would be useful when the site is in read-only mode.
Of course, there's currently no post at math.meta about why the site is in read-only mode, so it's not clear that the banner is providing any useful information.

Mentioned here which seems to be about the phenomenon that led me to see that banner.
